# ruby gems only installed in tmux

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I spend most of my time these days developing in a TMUX session. Recently however I tried using one of my ruby gems outside of tmux and it told me it wasn't installed. I installed it (again?!?) using gem install, but I didn't understand why I should have to as I didn't remember having removed it. To make things weirder, when I looked into it...

```
gem list
```

...and I get back a very small list of gems...not nearly all of the gems I'm pretty sure I've installed already...

Then I start up a tmux session, run gem list again and, surprise, all of my gems are there.

What's going on here? I'm using rvm so I figure it has something to do with the version of ruby being managed by rvm. I tested this by running 
    which ruby
in and out of tmux

```
$ which ruby
usr/bin/ruby
$ tmux new -s test
$ which ruby
/home/stephen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

I suspect this discrepancy is related, but I'm still stuck on two questions:

1. Why would I have to source ruby from somewhere different in tmux than on my terminal?
2. How do I fix this? Move ruby to the correct location via rvm? How do I do that?

Here's some additional info that may or may not be helpful

contents of .rvmrc:

```
rvm_autoupdate_flag=2
```

contents of .bashrc

```
export EDITOR=vim
export HIST_FILE_SIZE=9999

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

contents of .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Load the bashrc
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

[here's](https://gist.github.com/smcabrera/a8e8d95163573380786b) a list of my environment variables
and [here's](https://gist.github.com/smcabrera/03de50e2a2dca54203d5) the result of running the same command in a tmux session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use login shell for your terminal, the configuration varies depending on your terminal application - start here: http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal